# Multiple listview kivy

Tags: python, list, listview, kivy

with this i can display one list (l) , but how can i display the second one on it sides (l2) ?

```
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView    
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

liste=[{'Member': 'true', 'id': 'adresse1@example.com'},{'Member': 'true', 'id': 'adresse1@example.com'}]
mail=', '.join(d['id'] for d in liste)
members=', '.join(d['Member'] for d in liste)

l=mail.split(',')
l2=members.split(',')

class MainView(ListView): 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainView, self).__init__(item_strings=l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(MainView())
```

edit: I tried "listadapter" but I can't get how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you're using kivy 1.10, consider [not using ListView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html) and use RecycleView instead.

> ListView has been deprecated, use RecycleView instead.

If I understand correctly, you want to have two columns with values of `l` in one column and `l2` in the other.

To do this you can change your `MainView` to be a `BoxLayout` with two columns (or one row) and in the `__init__` add two list views to the `MainView`.

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

liste = [{'Member': 'true', 'id': 'adresse1@example.com'}, {'Member': 'true', 'id': 'adresse1@example.com'}]
mail = ', '.join(d['id'] for d in liste)
members = ', '.join(d['Member'] for d in liste)

l = mail.split(',')
l2 = members.split(',')


class MainView(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.columns = 2
        self.add_widget(ListView(item_strings=l))
        self.add_widget(ListView(item_strings=l2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(MainView())
```

And it looks like this: [image: ListView fixed app]

Please tell me if this was helpful or not and I will improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you , that's exactly what I want ! Do you know how to put a label on each column , and make them scroll all together ?

Comment: Yes, I do know how to do that. However, it all depends on how you want your app to look (will the label always be visible? or can you hide it by scrolling?) and how determined you are. 

I can help you if you want, but we'll have to get in touch. Do you use Discord, Slack, or just prefer the regular email?

Comment: I can't really discord  or Slack , let's go for regular email ?

Comment: You can reach me at edvardasdlugauskas@gmail.com . Be sure to first do your research and I will help you if you get stuck. But I won't do everything for you, obviously.